# SAP DB: SQL String Length Function?

Tags: sql, database, string

Is there a function for SAP DB to get the length of a string in SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the `length()` function exists, although it isn't listed in the [string funcions list](http://www.sapdb.org/7.4/htmhelp/71/81736bb9b311d2a97100a0c9449261/content.htm) in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

I use the len() function

edit: never mind - I'm on MSSQL